# What is the origin of the Hippogriff?

Tags: mythical-creatures, etymology

The Hippogriff is said to be the symbol of the Greek god Apollo.  A Hippogriff is a  mixture of a horse and an eagle/griffin. There are some practices that consider the Hippogriff a symbol of love. This is because the parents of a Hippogriff, (Griffin and the Mare) are natural enemies.

When was the Hippogriff  introduced as part of mythology?

Comment: They were first named in the Italian epic [*Orlando Furioso*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orlando_Furioso) by [Ludovico Ariosto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludovico_Ariosto), during the Renaissance. He took the classical griffin and crossed it with a mare.

Comment: "There are some practices that consider the Hippogriff a symbol of love."  Can you explain this statement a bit?

Comment: @Peter Yes. Because the Griffin and the Mare are considered natural enemies, the fact that they produced the Hippogriff together is a grand symbol of love. This is because it wasn't meant to be. Enemies aren't supposed to love each other. Do you understand?

Comment: @anonymous No. Your interpretation seems far fetched. Do you have any sources to back up that conclusion?

Comment: @Hamlet Yes. I have several sources. Here is a link to my search. As you will see, there are several sites saying that the hippogriff is a symbol of love.

Comment: @Hamlet Link: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=the%20hippogriff%20being%20a%20symbol%20of%20love

Comment: @Hamlet does that make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippogriff) in anonymous's Google search link, the hippogriff was first mentioned by the ancient Roman poet Virgil, in his *Ecologues*. ([Book VIII](http://sacred-texts.com/cla/virgil/ecl/ecl08.htm)) He doesn't give the creature a name, just uses the example of gryphons mating with horses to comment on a human relationship that seems equally unlikely.

The Roman emperor Augustus built a temple to Apollo decorated with a [hippogriff and dolphins](https://books.google.ca/books?id=icf1uZxZOj8C&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=Hippogriff%20Apollo&source=bl&ots=eEWg_E_9xR&sig=uM8hjoVvabL6uqWizwlKyQryfDw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVhsbHkJ7KAhVIwj4KHQgdCQg4ChDoAQg2MAk#v=onepage&q=Hippogriff%20Apollo&f=false). So we know that 1st-century Romans would understand a reference to a half-horse, half-gryphon. That doesn't necessarily mean that the hippogriff was a symbol of Apollo, however. The temple was built after the battle of Actium, so the dolphins are a reference to the sea battle, and the hippogriff may be a reference to Egypt.

*Orlando Furioso* may well be the first to give it a name, and a good name too. In any case hippogriffs aren't mythological per se - they feature in no myths. They're imaginary animals, and can carry symbolic freight, such as this idea that their parents are mortal enemies and so they're a symbol of love.

The oldest source I could find for the idea that gryphons and horses are enemies is [Isidore of Seville](http://bestiary.ca/beasts/beast151.htm), from the 7th century CE.

(Apparently in medieval times the unlikeliness of horses and gryphons mating became a [proverb](http://www.mythicalrealm.com/creatures/hippogriff.html).)